# Writing numbers in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

in SQL developer I am trying to insert data into a table, and I get an error at `price` and `sale price` where I have used `900.99` as the number.

```
INSERT INTO BIKES (MANUFACTURER_NAME, DEALER_NAME, BIKE_SIZE,
                   CLASSIFICATION, BIKE_ID, MODELS, PURCHASE_DATE,
                   PRICE, SALE_PRICE, SALE_DATE)
VALUES ('Superbike', 'Big Steve', 'Large male',
        'Mountain', 0884621 , 'Speed Demon X1', '15/Jan/14',
        900.99, 900.99, '25/Feb/14');
```

and I am using these boundaries:

```
PRICE number(6,2) CONSTRAINT PRICE_NN NOT NULL,
SALE_PRICE number(6,2) CONSTRAINT SALE_PRICE_NN NOT NULL,
```

Sorry for the simple question - only recently started using SQL.

--Edit--
Here is the full table:

```
CREATE TABLE BIKES (
MANUFACTURER_NAME VARCHAR2 (100),
DEALER_NAME VARCHAR2 (100),
BIKE_SIZE  VARCHAR2 (15),
CLASSIFICATION  VARCHAR2 (15),
BIKE_ID NUMBER (7),
PRIMARY KEY (BIKE_ID),
MODELS NUMBER(7) CONSTRAINT SIZE_NN NOT NULL,
PURCHASE_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT PURCHASE_DATE_NN NOT NULL,
PRICE number(6,2) CONSTRAINT PRICE_NN NOT NULL,
SALE_PRICE number(6,2) CONSTRAINT SALE_PRICE_NN NOT NULL,
SALE_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT SALE_DATE_NN NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (MANUFACTURER_NAME) REFERENCES MANUFACTURER(MANUFACTURER_NAME),
FOREIGN KEY (DEALER_NAME) REFERENCES DEALER(DEALER_NAME),
FOREIGN KEY (CLASSIFICATION, BIKE_SIZE)
  REFERENCES BIKE_SPECS(CLASSIFICATION, BIKE_SIZE));
```

and error message:

```
Error starting at line 298 in command:
INSERT INTO BIKES( MANUFACTURER_NAME, DEALER_NAME, BIKE_SIZE, CLASSIFICATION, BIKE_ID, MODELS, PURCHASE_DATE, PRICE, SALE_PRICE, SALE_DATE)
VALUES ('Superbike','Big Steve','Large male','Mountain',0884621 ,'Speed Demon X1','15/Jan/14',900.99,900.99,'25/Feb/14')
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: What are the types of the columns?  Are the `price` and `sale_price` columns decimals?

Comment: There is no problem if inserting value 900.99 into number(6,2) field, I checked it a seconds ago. Please provide full CREATE TABLE statement, your INSERT statement and error message, so we'll can catch what is wrong. By the way, inserting of 0884621 requires corrections.

Comment: The price should be $900.99 - so a number? I have tried decimal and it has given the same error, not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Please add the *exact* error message you get to your question.

Comment: i think he didnt understand the error code. I feel that error can be about PURCHASE_DATE column :)

Comment: The error  previously said column 99 which pointed to the price

Comment: @newuserua_ext is right. The error should be about purchase date and sale date. Try doing a to_date to convert the string value to a date format. Also see david a.'s comment about Models.

Comment: Might be your date format. Don't rely on implicit data type conversion. Use a proper date literal instead. Either through `to_date()` or an ANSI date litera: `date '2014-01-15'`

Comment: Your insert statement tries to insert ''Speed Demon X1' to the column MODELS, that is defined as NUMBER(7).

Comment: @jarlh, why did you roll back my edits? You added the "thanks" back, and the formatting is also rolled back. The grammar fixes are now gone. Can you please explain?

Comment: @LalitKumarB, Sorry, but I did never see your edit. Some kind of transaction conflict I'd say...

Comment: @jarlh, you should have seen the edit history. Anyway, either I would fix it back, or would you like to do it?

Comment: @LalitKumarB, I suppose it's better if you fix it, then it will be exactly as you want it. (I'd probably mess it up some way...)

Comment: @jarlh, alright, no issues. Some more work though ;-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry but, I had to first rollback previous edit and then I have put back your edit.

Comment: @jarlh, edit is now fixed. It became somewhat complex since I had to first rollback your edit and then put other's edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MODELS NUMBER(7)
>
> 'Speed Demon X1'

Seems like the above column data type NUMBER and the value as a string is causing the error.

Another thing,

> PURCHASE_DATE DATE
>
> '15/Jan/14'

`'15/Jan/14'` is NOT a **DATE**, rather a **string**. When you enclose a value within single quotation, it is considered a string. You must convert the **literal** into date using **TO_DATE** along with proper **FORMAT MODEL**. Never rely on **internal datatype conversion**.

Convert the literal to date, for example:

`to_date('15/Jan/14','DD/Mon/RR')`

To add more about **DATE**, always mention the year as **YYYY** and not just **YY**. You don't have to reinvent the Y2K bug. The world already saw the consequences and a lot of revenue was wasted to fix it. A year is supposed to be `2015` and not `15`.

Comment: '15/Jan/14' would be converted to date automatically (assuming it matches NLS settings of OP's DB session). Moreover, I also believe Oracle would give an error different than 'invalid number' if it could not parse a string to a date.

Comment: As I said, never rely on internal data type conversion. OP might just be lucky to get through the internal conversion. Anyway, there are multiple issues with OP's code.

Comment: Sorry not really related to my original question but how do you showcase TIME in oracle - is it hh/mm/ss? (for inserting data into a table)

Comment: @Harry, well a date column will have both date and time elements. Try `select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;` The latter part of the format model will display the time portion. So, while inserting date values, just use `to_date` and exact format model as that of the values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is NLS parameters ([NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams129.htm#REFRN10126)).

[How NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS parameter works](http://dbaora.com/nls_numeric_characters-as-easy-as-possible/)

And another useful link about [NLS parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_globalization.htm).

Comment: That parameter doesn't affect numeric literals though, only how strings are converted to numbers. The decimal separator is always a period in a numeric literal, and there is no group separator.